# How to implement sinc(x) in GLSL branchlessly?

Tags: math, glsl, trigonometry

I would like to implement the `sinc(x) = sin(x) / x` function in GLSL. This is my first attempt:

```c
float sinc(float x) {
    if (abs(x) < 1.0e-5) {
        return 1.0;
    } else {
        return sin(x) / x;
    }
}
```

It seems well, but I would like to avoid branches, so I changed it to:

```c
float sinc(float x) {
    return mix(1.0, sin(x) / x, step(1.0e-5, abs(x)));
}
```

But this expression has a possible division by zero expression. Is it possible to avoid that while keeping the code branch free?

Comment: The only case that needs to be tested is for x == 0, otherwise sin(x)/x is well defined, even for very small x. My advice is to just write it with the branch `if (abs(x) == 0.0) ...` and leave it at that -- it's much, much more important to get something which is correct, before looking at optimizations.

Comment: Depending on the semantics of `min()` in GLSL, `min(1, sin(x)/x))` *might* do the trick. I do not use GLSL, so I do not know what it prescribes for 0/0, or for NaN handling by `min()` (assuming it even supports NaNs).

Comment: Is `sin(x)` itself implemented branchless on your device? Do you care about (accurate) results for "large" `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your first attempt isn't that far off.

BTW Testing for equality with zero is marginally faster and works OK for true zero which is the only value that causes trouble for computing the division.

Sinc is an even function so that defining it for positive only values of x and avoiding exactly zero is sufficient. It is well behaved for any small non-zero x.

Although you might want to check that it is actually faster done this way.

```
float sinc(float x) {
   x = abs(x)+1e-14;   // add a tiny amount to avoid divide by zero
   return sin(x) / x;
}
```

Does what you have asked for at float precision.  You will also need to check in the disassembly that the implementation of abs(x) isn't hiding a conditional branch.

This adding a small constant trick is safe because for any reasonable value of x, 10^-14 is too small to alter the answer. And for very small x we can look at the polynomial expansion of sin(x)/x

sinc(x) = 1 - x^2/6

Once x^2/6 < machine_eps then sinc(x)==1 or sin(x) == x if you prefer.

For single precision this lower limit is at about x= 0.002 and for double precision it is around 2e-8.
10^-30 is a reasonable choice of fixup for double precision.

Depending on exactly what you are using it for and the range of x a lookup table might be faster still. Evaluating the function sin(x) is really quite slow and divisions have high latency too. I'd be surprised if you could measure the effect of the conditional branch here (especially if it is only taken when x==0.0). Better interpolating functions are available depending on what it is you want to do...

Comment: I dunno. Fudging the argument has the potential to introduce unexpected results. One might be able to prove it's harmless, but that's nontrivial.

Comment: I have added the analysis that shows adding such a small constant cannot affect the answer. It relies on the fact that once x is small and for single precision floating point sin(x) == x when x < 0.002. My choice of 10^-14 (~machine_eps^2) is quite conservative - it would still work exactly as intended if the constant was 10^-10.